# How to validate the country code with + sign in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I have a text box. There the user can enter the country code with + sign.

If he enters the numbers only, we should not allow him. He must enter the country code with + sign ex: +91, +230, ... I am searching for a regex in the internet. I could not find out a good solution in Angular 7.

Code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.registerFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      clientId: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')])],
      mobileNumber: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')])],
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.maxLength(1000)]) ],
      countryCode: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*$/')]), ],
    });

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `ngx-mask`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a regex staring with `+` and has the desired number of digits

```js
let regex = /^[+]\d{12}$/; // enter the total number if digits you want

let correct = '+911234567890'
let inCorrect = '911234567890'

console.log(regex.test(correct))
console.log(regex.test(inCorrect))
```

To use `\d` in angular form validators, it looks like we have to escape the  "backslash", so your pattern will be like:

```
Validators.pattern('^[+]\\d{12}$')
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdctcl?file=src/app/app.component.html

Alternatively you can use:

```
Validators.pattern('^[+][0-9]{12}$')
```

Comment: countryCode: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^[+]\d{12}$/')]) ],   I tried like this in angular 7. it is not working. can you please help me ?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal Don't add the staring and ending `/` while entering it as a pattern

Comment: I put like this . it is not working  Validators.pattern('^[+]\d{12}$')

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal I don't understand why is `\d` not working here, I will have a look. By then you can try something like: `[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[+][0-9]{12}$')]` See it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbzotq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: hi it is working but but i do not want to enter 12 numbers. i want to enter some numbers after + sign. can you please help me?? . we are very close to resolve this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192715/discussion-between-xyz-and-kumaresan-perumal).

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
ngOnInit() {

const patternData = /^[+]\d{12}$/;

this.registerFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      clientId: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')])],
      mobileNumber: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')])],
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.maxLength(1000)]) ],
      countryCode: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(patternData)]), ],
    });
    }
```

Comment: did you try to check pattern on html side?

Comment: how to add it in html. please tell me

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal i just update my answer if this is not working then we are thinking about to check pattern on html 
can you try this 
`const patternData = /^[+]\d{12}$/;`

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal let me know if it is working or not

Comment: countryCode: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[+]\d{12}$')]), ],

<div *ngIf="submitted && f.countryCode.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.countryCode.errors.pattern">Enter numeric value with + symbol</div>
                        </div>

Comment: Please refer my answer bcs currently in your code 
`: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[+]\d{12}$')]), ]
`
Instead of this try this 
`
const patternData = /^[+]\d{12}$/;
this.registerFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      countryCode: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(patternData)]), ],
    });
    }`

Comment: i do not want to enter 12 numbers. I may add 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 number after + sign. please help me

Comment: remove 12 from regex

Comment: Validators.pattern('^[+]\\d{1,}$')  I put it like this it is working

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal Okay